# Why is Wine separately bundled with Winebottler for Mac OSX?

Tags: mac, homebrew, windows, wine

I am trying to make use of [registax](https://www.astronomie.be/registax/) software for astrophotography image stacking on my Macbook. I first installed [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) which hanged on startup due to a known [Homebrew Core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26384) issue. This led me to directly install `Wine` from provided [.pkg file](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS). Now, I have `registax` running excellently within the `Wine` environment.

Before using `registax`, I also need to pre-process my Astro images using [PIPP](https://sites.google.com/site/astropipp/downloads/installing-pipp-on-macos-with-winebottler) software. It is installed via [Winebottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/). When I downloaded `WineBottlerCombo_1.8.6.dmg`, it also includes `Wine` app and asks me to drag-and-drop both `Wine` and `WineBottler` within `Applications` folder. But I already have `Wine stable` installed as explained above.

My doubts includes:

1. Do I also need `Wine` app bundled with `WineBottler`?
2. Is the bundled `Wine` app only used for Mac app package creation by `WineBottler`?
3. Should I just use `Wine` app bundled with `WineBottler` and uninstalled `Wine stable` I previously installed directly from `winehq`?

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling onto this question:

`Wine` is bundled with `Winebottler` as it is needed to create standalone Mac app packages *(this is how `winebottler` works, unsure why it cannot use vanilla `Wine (stable)` app)*.

So, both are needed:

1. `Wine (stable)` installed via `winehq` to run `Wine` applications
2. `Wine` installed via `winebottler` to create standalone Mac app packages